# Creating a VS 2019 Generate Type in new file refactoring extension

Tags: refactoring, roslyn, vsix

I heavily use the VS 2019 quick refactorings, particularly the "Generate Type in new file" refactoring.

However, this refactoring generates code with private members like this

```
    private FloorId id;
    private BuildingId buildingId;
    private SiteMapId siteMapId;
```

whereas I want public properties like

```
    public FloorId Id{get;}
    public BuildingId BuildingId{get;}
    Public SiteMapId SiteMapId{get;};
```

Also the class is generated with an internal access modifier on the class itself, and I want public.

I can't determine how to customise the code generation, so I thought I would create a custom VSIX Refactoring Project and build my own refactoring implementation.

I would like to try and find the source code for the "Generate class in new file" refactoring so that I can use that as a basis to build my own.

Does anyone know where I could find this code, or something similar?

It seems like creating custom refactorings VSIX projects is a rather niche subject, and not a great deal out there to work from.

Answer (score 1):

If you're unaware the "Generate new type..." option that's last in the refactoring list, that pops up a dialog that lets you customize some behavior, including the access modifier of the class. We don't let you choose properties but that's a good suggestion.

The C# engine for Visual Studio (Roslyn) is open source, so you can find at least a tiny bit of the code here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Features/Core/Portable/GenerateType. That said, there's a lot of code there and a huge amount of stuff it depends on...this is not trivial to rewrite and easily extract. You're probably best off trying to modify that and then running a custom Roslyn to experiment with. You may also want to consider opening an issue or discussion on the Roslyn repository, because honestly this might just be a feature we'd take via pull request.